# Trigger for inserting and updating multiple records in the same table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have table

```
    CREATE TABLE `seniority_master` (
  `EMPNO` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GENDER` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CATGRY` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DOB` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `DESG` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DESGTYPE` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SENIORITY` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `EMPTYPE` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TYPE` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QUAL` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BRANCH` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DOJ` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `DOCA` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `PAYSCALE` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OTHERDESC` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`EMPNO`,`SENIORITY`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `seniority_master` VALUES ('1389','MUNNA','Male','OBC','1959-10-31','SENIOR RECORD SORTER (ASS-I)','',2,'STAFF','P03','4th','AGRA','1982-07-01','2007-07-01','12100-24500','');
INSERT INTO `seniority_master` VALUES ('1391','RAJENDER SINGH','MALE','UR','1965-07-09','AM (GENERAL)','GENERAL',40,'OFFICERS','H1','INTER  ','AGRA','1984-06-22','2013-09-05','16400-40500','');
INSERT INTO `seniority_master` VALUES ('1392','MADAN GOPAL','Male','OBC','1966-07-04','SENIOR OFFICE MANAGERS-I (GENERAL)','',6,'STAFF','L1','10TH','AGRA','1984-08-17','2015-04-17','15600-30500','');
```

In the above data the **seniority(2,40,6)** of the employee is going to change every time when the promotion takes place based on the **type(P03,H1,L1)** of the employee.

What we really need is a Trigger that updates the **seniority** of all the other employees for the **type** when one of the employee is updated or inserted or deleted.

Ex: Suppose **empno** 4620 has **seniority** 5 and **type** A1, when we delete the particular **empno** in seniority_master table, the **seniority** of below employees of the same **type** to be updated automatically by increment or decrement based on the **seniority**. Similar procedure for updation and insertion operations to done.

I am able to create AFTER INSERT and AFTER UPDATE triggers for my program requirement.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_seniority_insert 
    AFTER INSERT ON seniority_master
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO emp_positions
   ( empno,
     position,
     dop)
   VALUES
   ( NEW.empno,
     NEW.desg,
     NEW.doca );
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

After update:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_seniority_update 
    AFTER UPDATE ON seniority_master 
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF (old.desg != new.desg &&
          old.doca != new.doca) then
   INSERT INTO emp_positions
   ( empno,
     position,
     dop)
   VALUES
   ( NEW.empno,
     NEW.desg,
     NEW.doca );
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Help me out for above scenario for creating trigger.

Comment: You cannot update the table which caused the trigger to fire. I suggest you log the inserts,deletes and updates and periodically adjust the seniorities.

Comment: Can you provide a example for logging and periodically update scenario

Comment: I have created a trigger for insert after update on one table DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_seniority_update 
    AFTER UPDATE ON seniority_master 
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF (old.desg != new.desg &&
          old.doca != new.doca) then
   INSERT INTO emp_positions
   ( empno,
     position,
     dop)
   VALUES
   ( NEW.empno,
     NEW.desg,
     NEW.doca );
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

Comment: @P.Salmon How to enable logging and adjust the seniorities periodically. Can you please provide sample for it.

Comment: I meant create a log table, then a trigger for each possible action (insert ,update,delete) to populate it and then a procedure for parsing the log table carrying out any appropriate actions and purging it when complete.

Comment: @P.Salmon Ok after taking the actions to log table. How to modify the seniority based on it. "A procedure for parsing the log table carrying out any appropriate actions and purging it when complete" can you explain in depth with a sample data.

Comment: @P.Salmon what are business rules.

Comment: @P.Salmon please help me out